# My AppBar is behind my Image on the screen or I can not see it, any suggestion to display my AppBar and buttomNavigator on top and translucent?

Tags: flutter, dart

My AppBar is behind my Image on the screen or I can not see it, any suggestion to display my AppBar and buttomNavigator on top and translucent?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          DisplayScreeImages(),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(
              title: Text('I am happy'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: share what you have in - `DisplayScreeImages(),`

Answer (score 1):

Your Scaffold should take the app bar.

Try the following:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('I am happy'
    ),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      DisplayScreeImages(),
    ],
  ),
),
```